# Amazon Cloudhosting and JPlayer

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mime-types, jplayer

I'm so confused with amazon's cloud hosting slash getting jplayer to work. I've tested their player (no deviation in html from the demos) on video files hosted on dropbox and it worked fine, except the bandwidth was too slow for my needs. I've tried replacing dropbox urls with amazon urls with no success.

Here is my JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "http://media.callserver.dyndns.biz.s3.amazonaws.com/Edited+Original+Intro.mp4",
                ogv: "http://media.callserver.dyndns.biz.s3.amazonaws.com/Edited+Original+Intro.ogv"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },ended: function (event) {
            $("#next").show();
                window.location.href = "http://callserver.dyndns.biz:90/index.php?action=TestVid";
            },swfPath: "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.0.0",
        supplied: "m4v, ogv"
    });
});
```

I've setup a bucket called media.callserver.dyndns.biz (my dynamic hostname from dyndns) following one of the tutorials. I did this after 'wunvideos' did not appear to work for a bucket name. I then created a streaming distribution, though i've questioned if i should not. At the same time, the urls that seem to actually work for downloading the file from browser are no combination of urls i can think for my cloudfront distribution. I'm utterly confused as to what to do.

Comment: So, specifically what is your question?

Comment: well, how can i get this to work? lol, if I knew what the problem was i'd be more specific but i don't...

Comment: I'm now relatively confident that the problem is that amazon s3 is not assigning the proper MIME types to my mp4 and ogv files. So the question is now, how can I SET these MIME types? I see no options for this in s3 firefox explorer or amazon's s3 explorer.

Comment: found a php script i can use to upload the files to the s3 server, now the player isn't working, guess i'll go pester the jplayer folks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if you've seen the link already but [working from this guide](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/2010/03/using-amazon-s3-to-host-streaming-videos/) there's a couple of differences with your description:

- Stick to the download option, not streaming, as it is faster and possibly more reliable
- Test the Cloudfront URL in your browser to make sure the URL is working
- Once that's all tested and working, embed it in a player of your choice - the guide uses JWPlayer

Maybe one of those will help, or at least help narrow the problem

Comment: that is a nice tutorial, looks pretty similar to what amazon s3 had. Ultimately i found i didn't even need a distribution to play the file. I found that probably the main problem was that the MIME types weren't set properly. I used a php script from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/) to upload the files to s3 which got the mime types, it appears to work, now i just got a fix a bug on my upload page :S